# Characters getting cut off by Mail app when launching from within my app

Tags: iphone, ios, email, character-encoding, url-encoding

I'm trying to set up a prefilled email for the user to send through the iphone native Mail application. The body of the email contains a link that the user wants to share.

My problem is that the link is getting cut off by the Mail app but when I print out the string in my app the whole link is there.

Here is a sample link:

```
http://sample.com/Start.asp?tqnm=xe2nbek92057479&bt=xg&o=100925&c=RB&p=2W7TvRx1
```

In the mail app the link shows up as:

```
http://sample.com/Start.asp?tqnm=xe2nbek92057479
```

I am using the standard code for launching the Mail app:

```
NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",
                        [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [body stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"Mail String: %@", mailString);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
```

I've also tried other string encodings but I either get the same result or the body of the email doesn't show up at all.

Any help would be really appreciated. I've been looking for the answer for a while and haven't found anything to even point me in the right direction.

Comment: try to replace all the `&` in your link with `%26`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it, I found this function

```
NSString* encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
return (NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) string,
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Then I used that to encode the body, which took care of the ampersand case, which Matthias was referring to. Thank you Matthias for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer so that question does not appear to still unanswered!

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps more a work-around than an answer, but... You might consider using the MessageUI framework to send the mail directly from within your app. You can easily set the body of the mail without any encoding issues and it also a little bit nicer for the user (i.e. does not switch away from your application).

There are plenty of tutorials/code snippets on the web about how to do this. (I wrote this one a while ago [Sending Mail from your App](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/25/snippet-sending-mail-for-your-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/)). Hope this helps!